# Which edges does this counter count?

Tags: counter

[This](https://www.mccdaq.com/pdfs/manuals/USB-1608GX.pdf) board has two counter inputs.

[image]

But is there a way to figure out whether the counter counts each rising or falling edges? Rising or falling edges?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the datasheet:

> The 
>   CTR0 and CTR 1 terminals are 32
>   -bit event counters that can accept frequency inputs up to 20MHz. 
>   The internal counter increments when the TTL levels transition from low to high.

Comment: Oh great catch I missed that part.

Comment: Btw the ground of the counter input(TTL level input) be connected to AGND or digital ground?

Comment: Either will do. AGND is intended for separating digital noise from digital side so, you shouldn't use AGND.